# replace content after tab 5 and 6 (regular expression)

Tags: java, regex

I got data with latitude and longitude, if they are unknown it's -1 for lat and -1 for long and then i get the correct location.
After that i want to store the file again with the correct lat and long to avoid a daily query limit. However for the purpose of learning and efficiency i don't want to do it like

```
id+"\t"+region+"\t"+ etc...
```

This is how the lines look like:

```
5   Canada  British Colombia    Vancouver   -1  -1
```

I'm guessing it must be possible with

```
lines[i].replaceAll("regex", lat);
lines[i].replaceAll("regex", lon);
```

or maybe even in one line.

What should the regex be?

Comment: Each line of this file should correspond to an instance of a class named (say) `City`; rather than having a `String[]`, as you apparently do, you should have a `City[]`. You'd then have logic for parsing a line of the file into a `City` instance, and for serializing a `City` instance back into a `String`. So then you would write `city[i].setLatitude(...)` and `city[i].setLongitude(...)` (or just `city[i].latitude = ...` and `city[i].longitutde = ...` if you want to be more honest about your level of encapsulation).

Comment: Presumably you are parsing the lines in the first place, to determine whether the lat/lon is -1? If, so reconstructing the line by adding strings might be easier...

Comment: i all ready have those classes, and i load the city's from another file. This file is just for the image based on the idea and the geo cause that's not represented in the other file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with:

```
line.replaceAll("^((?:[^\t]*\t){4})[^\t]*", "$1" + lat);
line.replaceAll("^((?:[^\t]*\t){5})[^\t]*", "$1" + lon);
```

Or both with one:

```
line.replaceAll("^((?:[^\t]*\t){4})[^\t]*\t[^\t]*", "$1" + lat + "\t" + lon);
```

Comment: that looks quite complex :)
It doesn't work by me:
`String line = "5\tCanada\tBritish Colombia\tVancouver\t-1\t-1";`
`float lat = -55.0545;`
`float lon = 55.8473;`

`line = line.replaceAll("^((?:[^\t]*\t){5})[^\t]*\t[^\t]*", "$1" + lat + "\t" + lon);`

`println(line);`

Comment: @clankill3r: Qtax simply miscounted the fields (or perhaps didn't realize that `British Columbia` is a single value). Your code should work if you change the `{5}` to `{4}`.

Comment: Ah yeah, I went by the title "replace content after tab 5 and 6". Thanks @ruakh, updated.

Answer (score 1):

> However for the purpose of learning and efficiency i don't want to do it like
>
> ```
>  id+"\t"+region+"\t"+ etc..
> ```

This is the best approach, I think when you are aiming for efficiency. Even more efficient might be using a StringBuilder with a predefined size.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line.length() + 15);
sb.append(id);
sb.append('\t');
sb.append(region);
// ....
```

Comment: why +4? in the string builder, since a latitude and a longitude can be quite long, so shouldn't it be longer?
And what makes the string builder more effiecient over ####id+"\t"+region+"\t"+ etc..

Comment: @clankill3r: Yeah, I didn't understand what is was. Thanks for noticing. I googled it and yes, indeed. Adding 15 would be better, I think.