# Regex to get content after third instance of a character

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm trying to create a regex to get the full file path of an URL. Since I know the input will always be a simple HTTP/HTTPS URL (e.g. *`http://www.example.org/path/to/file.js?a12345678`*), I can simply get anything that comes after the third `/`, including the slash.

The closest answer I found was [replace content after tab 5 and 6 (regular expression)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675783/replace-content-after-tab-5-and-6-regular-expresion), but it's a regex to get anything that comes **before** that character:

```
"http://www.example.org/path/to/file.js?a12345678".match(/^((?:[^\/]*\/){2})[^\/]*/)
```

returns

> `["http://www.example.org", "http://"]`

I need it to return `["/path/to/file.js?a12345678"]`

I currently use the regex from [Regex to get first word after slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735483/regex-to-get-first-word-after-slash-in-url/8896309#8896309) but it's wasteful, as I don't need specific path parts, only the full path including query strings and fragment identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 1. [✽ Want to Be Lazy? Think Twice.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#lazy_warning)

```
https?:\/\/[^/]*(\/.*)
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/cL3zD4/7)

sample code:

```
var str="http://www.example.org/path/to/file.js?a12345678";
alert(str.match(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*(\/.*)/i)[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like this:

```
https?:\/\/.*?(\/.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iS8uT7/3)**

[image]